# How can I make my screen render a bigger tile for my tile game?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public void render(int xp, int yp, int tile, int colors, int bits) {
    xp -= xOffset;
    yp -= yOffset;
    boolean mirrorX = (bits & BIT_MIRROR_X) > 0;
    boolean mirrorY = (bits & BIT_MIRROR_Y) > 0;

    int xTile = tile % 32;
    int yTile = tile / 32;
    int toffs = xTile * 8 + yTile * 8 * sheet.width;

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        int ys = y;
        if (mirrorY) ys = 7 - y;
        if (y + yp < 0 || y + yp >= h) continue;
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (x + xp < 0 || x + xp >= w) continue;

            int xs = x;
            if (mirrorX) xs = 7 - x;
            int col = (colors >> (sheet.pixels[xs + ys * sheet.width + toffs] * 8)) & 255;
            if (col < 255) pixels[(x + xp) + (y + yp) * w] = col;
        }
    }
}
```

I followed a tutorial on youtube to get that method created but it only renders tiles that are 8x8 off of a sprite-sheet. I want to make it render tiles that are 32x32 but when i change it to all the 8s to 32s like this:

```
public void render(int xp, int yp, int tile, int colors, int bits) {
    xp -= xOffset;
    yp -= yOffset;
    boolean mirrorX = (bits & BIT_MIRROR_X) > 0;
    boolean mirrorY = (bits & BIT_MIRROR_Y) > 0;

    int xTile = tile % 32;
    int yTile = tile / 32;
    int toffs = xTile * 32 + yTile * 32 * sheet.width;

    for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
        int ys = y;
        if (mirrorY) ys = 7 - y;
        if (y + yp < 0 || y + yp >= h) continue;
        for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
            if (x + xp < 0 || x + xp >= w) continue;

            int xs = x;
            if (mirrorX) xs = 7 - x;
            int col = (colors >> (sheet.pixels[xs + ys * sheet.width + toffs] * 32)) & 255;
            if (col < 255) pixels[(x + xp) + (y + yp) * w] = col;
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1184
    at orbis.src.Screen.render(Screen.java:79)
    at orbis.src.TileWater.render(TileWater.java:37)
    at orbis.src.World.renderBackground(World.java:143)
    at plixel.orbis.Orbis.render(Orbis.java:383)
    at plixel.orbis.Orbis.run(Orbis.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post this question to the video you watched on Youtube.

Comment: Can you point out which line is 79 in your code snippet?? And the error clearly suggests you are calculating incorrect bounds for array and the title is not at all related to the problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the whole code I can't be sure, but assuming `line 79` accesses the `pixels` array you access an elemnt out of bounds.

Presumably one of the two expressions  `xs + ys * sheet.width + toffs` and `(x + xp) + (y + yp) * w` becomes <strike>larger than your array `pixels`</strike> negative (see **Andrew Thompsons** comment.

On a side note, it seems that `if (mirrorY) ys = 7 - y;` is supposed to flip the increase of `y` therefor it shoud read `if (mirrorY) ys = 32 - 1 - y;` (I guess). THe same would go for flipping the x coordinate. I assume that this is the cause for the expression becoming **negative**.

On a further note: you might have to update the array bounds:
Example:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
array[10];
```

This would yield an out of bounds error, either change the size of the array to 11 or access `array[9]` instead.

---

In general it is a good idea to use **constants** instead of hardcoding sizes that occur in many places and are subject to change. In java you could use `public static final` to declare a constant.

Comment: `Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1184`  From the number `-1184` we can presume the code is not going past the *end* of the array..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: good point, with what we have I have to asusme now that this is due to the incorrect reversal of `x` or `y` as stated in the bottom of my awnser, thus the whole expression becoming negative.